# VBA Insert Data from Excel to Word header

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am transfering data from Excel to Word using search words.

So i got placeholders in the Word document with I am searching and replacing like this:

```
Word.Content.Find.Execute FindText="TAG", ReplaceWith:="Data", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

This works totally fine, but it does not apply to tags in the header, which I want to do right now.

So is there anyway to change my command to also search and replace a tag in the header? Or is there any other way to insert data into a specific position in the header (bookmarks also doesn't work for me).

I would appreciate any kind of help! Thank you <3